# Save names of raster produced in loop with different names in R

Tags: r, loops, raster

I am trying to create 5 raster files and write each raster file with a separate name. So far, I have managed to achieve this:

```
c=5
for (i in 1:c){
z<-RFsimulate(x=x,y=y,grid=TRUE,model = model,maxGB=4.0)
a<-raster(z)
projection(a) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
writeRaster(raster(a),filename="raster[i].tif")
}
```

But I find only one raster file (raster 1) in my working directory. I thought I will have five raster files names raster1, raster2.....raster5. Could anyone help me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very basic R question. You should probably practice a bit with simple loops. Use `print` statements to see what is going on. Note that you create object `a` but you do not use it. `"raster[i].tif"` is a string, it has no relation to iterator `i`. Here is a solution:

```
n <- 5
for (i in 1:n){
    z <- RFsimulate(x=x,y=y,grid=TRUE,model = model,maxGB=4.0)
    a <- raster(z, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
    f <- paste0('raster', i, '.tif')
    writeRaster(a, filename=f)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

R does not have automatic string interpolation. If you want to put the value of `i` into the `filename` string, you'll need to explicitly substitute it. Instead try this:

```
   ...
   projection(a) <- ...
   filename <- gsub("INDEX", i, "raster_INDEX.tif")
   writeRaster(raster(z), filename=filename
}
```

This code uses the `gsub` function to substitute the token `"INDEX"` in a passed string with the value of `i`, and returns the modified string.

You could alternatively construct the file name with `paste`

```
 filename <- paste("raster_", i, ".tif", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little to the answers provided, because it is also useful to know how you can include a directory path into the file naming process. If the raster was stacked, you can retain the name of the original using `basename()`:

```
##Set the lists
list_dirs <- list.dirs(getwd(), recursive = FALSE)
stack.list <- list()

##Loop the rasters into a stack
for (i in 1:length(list_dirs)){

    rasters <- list.files(path=list_dirs[i], pattern = ".tif$", recursive=FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
    stack.list[[basename(list_dirs)[i]]] <- stack(rasters)

    ##Useful to shorten the names of the raster bands (e.g., Sentinel-2)
    stack.list2[[basename(list_dirs)[i]]] <- setNames(
           stack.list[[basename(list_dirs)[i]]],
           c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B11", "B12", "B8A")
           )  

    writeRaster(stack.list, filename = file.path("C:/Your Directory", paste0(basename(list_dirs)[i], i, "_stack")), overwrite=TRUE)
   }
```